# as3 checkbox in datagrid

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am new to Flash and AS3.
I have a DataGrid like this

```
  col1        col2     col3    col4
[checkbox]   value    value    value
[checkbox]   value    value    value
[checkbox]   value    value    value
[checkbox]   value    value    value
```

Datagrid fill dynamically from mysql using services.100 record per page in datagrid.
if i select some checkboxes and goto next page and select few other than come back to page 1.there should be checked checkboxes which i select previously.

I have the page 1 checkboxes value in php session and i can access these values in flash but i don't know how to set checboxes checked = true;
because there is not CHANGE event occurring on checkbox.

i am using bellow class.
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=234416

Plz help me anyone

@Josh Mohan

:( no luck. Can u plz plz check the below code. and correct me how to call

CheckCellClass.onCheckChange (new Event(Event.CHANGE));

function showSearchCriteria(returnObj:Object) { // RETURN is the value from database
    var varName:String;
    for (varName in returnObj) {

```
    /* NOTE : In this loop i want to set checkbox boxes to be checked. i mean selected = true;*/

    var plid                        = int   (returnObj[varName]   ["plid"]); //THIS IS GOING TO ASSIGN TO CHECKBOX
    var varState            = String(returnObj[varName]["state"]);
    var varCity             = String(returnObj[varName]["city"]);
    var varacgmeid          = String(returnObj[varName]["acgmeid"]);
    var varProgramname      = String(returnObj[varName]["programname"]);
    var varUrl              = String(returnObj[varName]["url"]);
    var varNoofseats        = int   (returnObj[varName]["noofseats"]);
    var varDeadline         = String(returnObj[varName]["deadline"]);
    var varYearofpassing    = int   (returnObj[varName]["passYear"]);
    var varScore            = int   (returnObj[varName]["stepone2digit"]);
    var varSteponeattempt   = int   (returnObj[varName]["steponeattempt"]);
    var varObservership     = int   (returnObj[varName]["observership"]);
    var varExternship       = int   (returnObj[varName]["externship"]);
    var varj1h1bf1          = String(returnObj[varName]["visa"]);
    var varProgramtype      = String(returnObj[varName]["programtype"]);
    var varComment          = String(returnObj[varName]["comment"]);
    var varContact          = String(returnObj[varName]["contact"]);

    //plid.onCheckChange (new Event(Event.CHANGE));
    arrDP.push({
      //Column            Value
       Select           : plid, 
       State            : varState,
       City             : varCity,
       ACGMEID          : varacgmeid,
       ProgramName      : varProgramname,
       NoofnSeats       : varNoofseats,
       Deadline         : varDeadline,
       YearFromPassing  : varYearofpassing,
       Scores           : varScore,
       Attempts         : varSteponeattempt,
       UsExperience     : varObservership,
       NoofMonths       : varExternship,
       VisaSponsored    : varj1h1bf1,
       Type             : varProgramtype,
       More             : "Show"
    }); //push end here..
} //for end here..

var dp:DataProvider              = new DataProvider(arrDP);

var select:DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("Select");
var state :DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("State");
var city  :DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("City");
var acgmeid :DataGridColumn      = dg.addColumn("ACGMEID");
var programname :DataGridColumn  = dg.addColumn("ProgramName");
var noofseats:DataGridColumn     = dg.addColumn("NoofnSeats");
var deadline:DataGridColumn      = dg.addColumn("Deadline");
var yearofpassing:DataGridColumn = dg.addColumn("YearFromPassing");
var scores:DataGridColumn        = dg.addColumn("Scores");
var attempts:DataGridColumn      = dg.addColumn("Attempts");
var usexperience:DataGridColumn  = dg.addColumn("UsExperience");
var noofmonths:DataGridColumn    = dg.addColumn("NoofMonths");
var visasponsored:DataGridColumn = dg.addColumn("VisaSponsored");
var type:DataGridColumn          = dg.addColumn("Type");
var more:DataGridColumn          = dg.addColumn("More");

select.cellRenderer              = ButtonRenderer; //CELL RENDER FOR CHECKBOX       

dg.dataProvider         = dp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The class you are using has overriden the Checkbox class' setter for the `selected` property, thereby making it impossible to check or uncheck the box using the `selected` property.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/LabelButton.html#selected

CODE:

```
override public function set selected(value:Boolean):void { 
}
```

**SOLUTION**:
Without changing your class to allow your setter to change the `selected` property of the superclass, two options are:

A) Call the event handler `onCheckChange` manually and pass it a null event or dummy event:

```
CheckCellClass.onCheckChange (new Event(Event.CHANGE));
```

B) Dispatch an `Event.CHANGE` event into the event stream to trigger the event handler:

```
CheckCellClass.dispatchEvent (new Event (Event.CHANGE));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
by calling CheckCellClass.onCheckChange (new Event(Event.CHANGE));
it throws the following error:1061: Call to a possibly undefined method onCheckChange through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: Replace 'CheckCellClass' with a reference to the checkbox you are trying to toggle.

Comment: :( no luck. Can u plz plz check the below code. and correct me how to call -> CheckCellClass.onCheckChange (new Event(Event.CHANGE));

Comment: in above code the ButtonRenderer is the class name, which i change from "CheckCellClass".

Comment: I have added my code bellow my question can you please guide me how to call the onCheckChange function.

Comment: Hello, in your original post you said you were using the CheckCellClass as your cellRenderer (definition found here: [link](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=234416)). In the code you posted you assign `select.cellRenderer` to the class `ButtonRenderer` instead. I'll need to see the definition for `ButtonRenderer` in order to provide further help.